# How to act in new job

Tags: professionalism, management, communication

Background: I got this job through a very competitive selection process and therefore managers have big expectations on me.

We are a team of 10 people and me and one other of those 10 are designated for a specific area, which I already had worked with. So this guy has less experience than me in the area but of course more time in the company so he knows more about procedures etc.

On our first assignment after I got in I had to watch the procedure of his screen because I don't have access to everything yet. I thought that was ok even though I could the tasks myself.

In the middle of this our manager spoke to me and told me that I should take the leash and tell him what to do sometimes. Some time passed, we finished our assignment with me trying to help however I could. Always limited by the lack of access.

Now he(colleague) is assigning me what to do and updated a sheet with some administrative to do every week and he has me on the leash.

I am not sure what do here, I asked my manager for access 2 weeks ago and he told that would come naturally in time. I can't really do a lot of stuff without the access and sometimes I find myself asking the guy what to do.

Should I go straight to the manager and tell him about this situation?

Comment: What answer other than "*Yes, talk to your manager.*" did you expect to get?

Comment: It was suppose to be a question for both things. My colleague telling me what to do and the access issue.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with taking direction as a newbie from a colleague with more time with the company -- as long as the tasks are within what would be normally assigned to someone like yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Of course. He wants you to do X and you can't do X for physical reasons. One of the tasks of a manager is to enable his people to get work done.

Don't complain, just do requests:
*I have no access yet, so I can't do X. How can I get access ASAP or do you have to arrange that?*

Or in your specific case:
*I still have no access, so I can't do X. Is there something you or I can do to get this working?*

Comment: What about him telling me what to do? Giving me tasks? I don't feel I should be taking directions from him but I don't want to complain about that to the manager.

Comment: @TKT This is a bit tangential to the question. But again, answer is "talk to the manager". You can always ask "Mr Y asked me to do X, is it the task I am supposed to do?" and later in the same conversation ask gently why don't you get your tasks directly from your manager. Sometimes it's someone trying to rule you with no authority. Sometimes it's natural. Currently I have no problem with accepting tasks from colleagues, even younger and less experienced ones. I have my freedom to tell them "no, this you need to put thorough my manager", but we don't bother management unless needed.

Comment: @TKT Then who are you taking directions from? I was assuming your manager. Please edit your question and put that information in - this may totally change the 'correct' answer!

Comment: edited @JanDoggen